# Hibernate : programmatically adding an index

Tags: hibernate, jpa

How can I add an index to a database column definition of a property.

Pseudo code will be something like,

```
//Iterate through the mappings of all persistent classes.

if(entityClass instanceOf MyClass) {

  // get version property of the class
  // make sure an index is added in the schema for that column
}
```

Is it possible ? I am using JPA with Hibernate as a persistent provider

Comment: Use SQL. Hibernate isn't the right tool to alter the structure of the database.

Comment: I am using Hibernate's Schema generator to create SQL Schema.